How to do an Apex class test coverage
How can i test this code, and The response class os on another page
global class Taxa_datadas {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Conversion Rates' description='Retrieve and sum conversion rates within a date range')
    public static List<List<Response>> Taxa_datadas(List<InputVar> inputVar) {
        List<List<Response>> outputResponse = new List<List<Response>>();

        // Get the inputs
        Date firstDate = inputVar.get(0).firstDate;
        Date finalDate = inputVar.get(0).finalDate;
        String isoCode = inputVar.get(0).isoCode;

        // Query DatedConversionRate with firstDate and finalDate
        List<DatedConversionRate> conversionRates = [SELECT ConversionRate, StartDate
                                                     FROM DatedConversionRate
                                                     WHERE StartDate >= :firstDate
                                                     AND NextStartDate <= :finalDate
                                                     AND isoCode = :isoCode
                                                     ORDER BY StartDate ASC];

        // Initialize list to hold responses
        List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();

        // Add conversion rates to responses list
        for (DatedConversionRate rate : conversionRates) {
            Response response = new Response();

            response.conversionRate = String.valueOf(rate.ConversionRate);
            response.startDate = String.valueOf(rate.StartDate);
            responses.add(response);
        }

        // Add responses list to outputResponse
        outputResponse.add(responses);

        return outputResponse;
    }

    public class InputVar {
        @InvocableVariable
        public Date firstDate;

        @InvocableVariable
        public Date finalDate;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String isoCode;
    }

    public class Response {
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
        public String conversionRate;

        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
        public String startDate;
    }
}


The same way you write any other test. How do I write an Apex Unit Test is a good place to start if you're completely new to testing.

I'm trying here, I'll show you what happened later, thanks.

N.B. this invocable only works for 1 input interview (i.e. is not bulkified). This might be OK for a screen flow but not for a record-triggered flow, not for a schedule-triggered flow, not for if the invocable is called in batch via REST

i did it, i still confuse but i did it, here is the code:
@isTest
public class Taxa_datadasTest {
@isTest
static void testTaxa_datadas() {
    // Given
    Taxa_datadas.InputVar input = new Taxa_datadas.InputVar();
    input.firstDate = Date.newInstance(2023, 1, 1); // Exemplo de data inicial
    input.finalDate = Date.newInstance(2023, 12, 31); // Exemplo de data final
    input.isoCode = 'USD'; // Exemplo de código ISO

    List<Taxa_datadas.InputVar> inputs = new List<Taxa_datadas.InputVar>();
    inputs.add(input);

    // When
    Test.startTest();
    List<List<Taxa_datadas.Response>> result = Taxa_datadas.Taxa_datadas(inputs);
    Test.stopTest();

    // Then
    System.assertNotEquals(null, result, 'Result should not be null');
    System.assertEquals(1, result.size(), 'Output response should contain exactly one list of responses');
    List<Taxa_datadas.Response> responses = result.get(0);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, responses, 'List of responses should not be null');

    
    if (!responses.isEmpty()) {
        for (Taxa_datadas.Response response : responses) {
            System.assertNotEquals(null, response.conversionRate, 'Conversion rate should not be null');
            System.assertNotEquals(null, response.startDate, 'Start date should not be null');
            System.assertEquals('USD', input.isoCode, 'ISO Code should match');
        }
    }
}

}
